# Connect the relationship between category,subcategory and gig

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, categories

My application has categories,than subcategories,than gigs

I have gigs_controller.rb in my controller file

And category.rb, subcategory.rb, gig.rb in my Model file.

How do i make their connection with each other,following the principle of category=subcategory=gig(by gig i mean i lot of small adds)

Will it be right to say in Category.rb model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories
end
```

in my Subcategory Model

```
class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

and in my Gig.rb

```
class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category # I also need here to be belongs_to :subcategory,how do i do that?
end
```

Should i create a controller for category and subcategory ?, how would you go about that.
Thank you,for your support,hope my question will help others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories
end


class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :gigs
end


class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subcategory
end
```

Comment: I just tried "category".pluralize  in rails console, and it worked,but when i do "subcategory".pluralize it gives an error. Will it affect the relationship described above? should i edit the subcategory model to sub_category?

Comment: When I run `"category".pluralize` I get `categories`. When I run `"subcategory".pluralize` I get `subcategories`

Comment: thanks a lot!) you said in your answer in Gig.rb  belongs_to :sub_category, can i say belongs_to :subcategory?  why did you use the underscore ''_'' line ? for subcategory

Comment: I have made a mistake by typing sry

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can use has_many in model without having a controller.Because has_many uses table's name.

`class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base`

`belongs_to :user`

`belongs_to :subcategory`

`end`

`class Category < ActiveRecord::Base`

`has_many :subcategories`

`end`

`class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base`

`belongs_to :category`

`has_many :gigs`

`end`